# "<Some program on Windows> has stopped working"

Tags: windows

I have been running mercurial (on Windows) for many months and I am suddenly now getting the error "Mercurial Distributed SCM has stopped working" in a Windows dialog. I can't find anything by searching on the web. Is this a question of reinstalling or is it more fundamental?

EDIT:
Because of the helpful answer indicating that this is a Windows problem I have changed the title

Comment: I have reinstalled and it has gone away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be more fundamental that just a reinstall, and it can happen for all sort of programs (not limited to "Mercurial Distributed SCM")

[image: example of "has stopped working" dialog box]

[This article](http://www.computertipsfree.com/exe-has-stopped-working-how-to-disable-windows-error-report-windows-7/) explains that, if a reinstall isn't enough:

> If for some reason you still can't get ride of this error, we recommend you to download the most popular registry repair tool, **[Registry Easy](http://www.registryeasy.com/)** to fix this error

Comment: Poor doze users and their problems ;)